# Pointers on member of the structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

http://i64.tinypic.com/34ffxx2.jpg

Please have a look at that image. ( Link given above)

In the book, it is stated that the 'next' member of structure variable 'n1' will point to the 'value' member of structure variable 'n2'.

1:) Won't it point to the complete 'n2' structure since 'n2' is a structure variable and the 'next' pointer is pointing to 'n2' and not particularly to its 'value' member.

2:) Also, it is stated that it is completely fine for a structure to contain another structure with same name and data type. How's that possible? I get it we can have as many structures in a parent structure, but how come a member has a data type of the parent structure ?

Comment: 1. It says next member of n1 will point to n2. It never says value member of n2.
2. it says, its fine to contain the pointer of the 'entry' structure.

Comment: I cannot read any sentence stating that `next` points to some `value` member. It states it points to an entry structure. This is exactly what you expect in 1). It also does not tell anything about containing another member with same type. It is a _pointer_ to same type as the struct which is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups. The *book* is right, but your understanding is wrong...

1. `n1.next` actually points to `n2`. It just happens that `value` is the first member of the struct so it lies at same address as the whole struct
2. What is stated is that it is fine for a struct is that one of its elements **points** to another struct of same type. But it cannot *contain* it. This is a compilation error:

   ```
   struct entry {
       int value;
       struct entry next;  // Ouch, tries to contain self: ERROR!
   };
   ```